Using android.car in Qt
I need to use android.car library in Qt project. The problem is in generating an apk, (Ui application) in which we are suppose to use APIs provided by the android.car. The integration of android.car in qt is trying to be achieve. Whereas this android.car is not supported in open source QT version. How can the API provided by android.car, (CarServices) be used in the application developed in Qt open source.
I am new to AAOS. I tried to invoke the APIs provided by java classes (like CarPropertyManager, carInfoManager...) , but it leads to linking issues.
All I need is, the values updated in the APIs of java classes (like CarPropertyManager, carInfoManager...) needs to be accessible from the Qt application without Qt for android automotive.
Qt for Android Automotive provides QtCarServices. Without this, We need to access the android.car directly. Is this possible in QT open source.
